# Jenkins in Azure VM "This site can’t be reached" at 8080

Tags: java, azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I attempted to add the `nvm-wrapper` plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/nvm-wrapper/) to jenkins and reboot and am no longer able to reach the site (This site can’t be reached). It is deployed as an azure VM. The VM is running, I can ssh in and `systemctl status jenkins.service` is showing:

```
jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-04-04 21:04:43 UTC; 14h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2530 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=7)

Apr 04 21:04:42 pipeline jenkins[2530]: Correct java version found
Apr 04 21:04:42 pipeline jenkins[2530]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Apr 04 21:04:42 pipeline su[2587]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Apr 04 21:04:42 pipeline su[2587]: + ??? root:jenkins
Apr 04 21:04:42 pipeline su[2587]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Apr 04 21:04:42 pipeline su[2587]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user jenkins
Apr 04 21:04:43 pipeline jenkins[2530]:    ...fail!
Apr 04 21:04:43 pipeline systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7
Apr 04 21:04:43 pipeline systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 04 21:04:43 pipeline systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

I had previously been running into `Incorrect Java version` due to having installed Java 12, so I modified the `/etc/init.d/jenkins` like so:

```
# Which Java versions can be used to run Jenkins
JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSIONS=( "18" "110" "120" )
# Work out the JAVA version we are working with:
JAVA_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\..*".*/\1\2/p;')
```

to allow for Java 12. Any thoughts on how/why either the plugin addition or Java version and/or `/etc/init.d/jenkins` edit could be impacting things? My sense is that the initial reboot failed due to the `Incorrect Java version` issue, but not sure how I can resolve things and get it back up and running. It should, by default, be available at 8080 and that is where I am seeing `This site can’t be reached`.

I also have the networking set up like so: [image]

and port 8080 should allow traffic. I have attempted to restart, hard start and stop/start to no avail as well. "Resource health" says the VM is available which should be obvious since it is running and I can ssh in. Do I need to redeploy perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

First, please delegate the service to a non root user.
Second, azure, means in the net, please use SSL, the times without SSL are gone.

```
JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSIONS=( "18" "110" "120" )
```

you are trying java 12, but its configured java 120, i think you should fix that to

```
JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSIONS=( "18" "11" "12" )
```